# How can I fade-in and fade-out between two contents on same page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsp, animation, fade

I am developing a page in JSP. It has 3 components: Header, Content and Footer. I want that when this page loads the Content part should be fade in to default content i.e. the Home Page, which contains button for register, login and site credits. When user clicks register button, the content in Content part should fade out and vanish and then content of register form should fade in and get displayed. Same for other buttons, but there should not be any change in header and footer. Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With use of jQuery... You have working example [there](http://jsfiddle.net/Cj7hZ/)...

Comment: Thanks PrimosK, thats what I really wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a JavaScript library to achieve this.

jQuery has [built in fading abilities.](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/)

```
<div id="clickme">
      Click here
    </div>
    <img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123" />
    With the element initially hidden, we can show it slowly:
    $('#clickme').click(function() {
      $('#book').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Peter for that fade in out code and jQuery API link but my main question is how to change content of a HTML page using javascript when user clicks something. For example as I explained before that when user clicks register button it should change to register content but only one <div> other divs should be unchanged and secondly when user clicks back button it should change  to previous content of DIV again no change in other divs or no page reload. And when changing content it should fade in out. Hope I was able to explain correctly as my english is somewhat week ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery, you can hide a div by using a selector and the `hide()` method. For example:

```
<html>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function swap_divs() {
        $("#div_to_hide").hide();
        $("#div_to_show").show();
      }
   </script>
   <body>
     <div id="div_to_hide">
       Some text for div to hide
     </div>
     <div id="div_to_show" style="display: none;">
       Some text for div to show
     </div>
     <button onClick="swap_divs();">Click me</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

If you look at the [JQuery website](http://jquery.com) you can find more example and extensive documentation. Also for fading in/fading out.